# Color Code Dataframe in Scatter Plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Lets say I have the following dataframe:

```
X    Y     Category
1    2         A 
5    3         B 
-1   1         C 
7    0         A 
1    2         B 
...
```

I want to find a way to color code the output of `df['X']` and `df['Y']` depending on their category (`df['Category']`).

I have tried this so far:

```
cm = pd.unique(df['Category'])
plt.scatter(data['X'], data['Y'], c=cm)
```

but it's telling me

```
c of shape (37,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 67725, y with size 67725
```

Comment: Is it a typo or intentional that you have used different dataframes in each line??

Comment: Do note that the color codes play an important role here. 'A' doesnt denote any color.

Comment: @Dark I think it's a typo, im just typing out the info in a table format. 'A' doesnt, but I need to make a distinction between different categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe an use pandas plot.

```
df.set_index(['X','Category'])['Y'].unstack().plot(marker='o',linestyle='none')
```

Output:

[image]

Or you can use seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
_ = sns.pointplot(x='X',y='Y', hue='Category', data=df, linestyles='none')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is much simpler to do this using a higher-level library such as `seaborn`, specifically through [`seaborn.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lmplot(x=X, y=Y, huge='Category', data=df)
```

and let it take care of the details.

See [Plotting With Categorical Data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html) to see `seaborn`'s other options for plotting categorical data.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CoCVq so that's the output of the data, not really sure why it's doing that

Comment: @user287474 From a glance, it seems like your dataset is dominated by Laceny/Theft. It is possible also that a scatterplot is not the best way to visualize 37 categories (as you seem to have). Please take a look at the link above for visualizing categorical data, and consider the options there as well.